# places suggestion not loading in Place Auto complete

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

PlacesAutoComplete not showing suggestion

```
AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment;
autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);
autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));
autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                //Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
                full_address.setText(place.getAddress().toString());
                pLoc=place.getAddress().toString();
                Log.i("TAG place", "Place: " + place.getAddress());
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Log.i("TAG Place", "An error occurred: " + status);
            }
        });
autocompleteFragment.setHint("Location");
```

Placesautocomplete is working fine but it is deprecated.
When I am migrating to Autocomplete instead of Placeautocomplete I get an error like this:
Help me to over come this problem

[image]

Comment: Check you logcat window, might be you have crossed per day search limit of places

Comment: Error while autocompleting: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Comment: What is the daily limit of places

Comment: Its working fine with older version but in new it does not